# Update Wordpress : Download failed.: The checksum of the file does not match the expected checksum value

Tags: wordpress, checksum

I have created a website on Wordpress. In admin panel I receive an error saying - "Download failed.: The checksum of the file (cc3d0faf742ebff553fd9f024f9a3096) does not match the expected checksum value (f4a544f0d250c08b5648bc36dea26f8e)."

Have done all recommended action. Set - mbstring.func_overload to 0. Space on server is 50% free. Gave 775 permissions to folder.

This is how my wordpress admin folder contains as attached. Please advise.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYqs7.jpg)